# nested for to create report

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to create report that summarize data in the table by using nested for

First this is how my table look

```
--------B------------------C------------------D-----------------E------

----inspector_1----inspector_2----inspector_3--------date 

-------Mark------------ Jhon----------- sare------------ 8/21/2019

Jhon---------------------------------------------------- 8/22/2019

sare--------------------Mark-----------------------------8/27/2019

Jho---------------------Mark------------sare-------------8/29/2019
```

user will enter the start and end date of report then i will show a form that count how many  time Mark, Jhon and sara visited the factories.

I will show the summary in userform named ReportForm 
the ReportForm  has three texbox in text box1 i will show how many Mark viseted the factories,  the other two boxes are for  Jhon and sara.

I listed the inspector names in sheet2 the range is F1:F3
here is my code but it did not work and it is seem that ReportForm.Controls is throwing error.

```
Dim BoxNo, inspNo As Long
For inspNo = 1 To 3
inspector  = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(inspNo , "F").Value
For BoxNo = 1 To 3
m1= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("e8:e2333"), "<=" & enddate, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("e8:e2333"), ">=" & startdate, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b8:b2333"), inspector)
m2=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("e8:e2333"), "<=" & enddate, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("e8:e2333"), ">=" & startdate, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c8:c2333"), inspector )
m3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("e8:e2333"), "<=" & enddate, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("e8:e2333"), ">=" & startdate, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("d8:d2333"), inspector  )
tot = m1 + m2 + m3
ReportForm.Controls("TextBox" & BoxNo).Value = tot
Next BoxNo
Next inspNo 
End
show ReportForm
```

Comment: where is `test.controls` in the above? Also you do realise that `BoxNo` is declared as a variant...

Comment: Thank you for your note. I just edit the post again. I was mean ReportForm.Controls and I edit BoxNo as well.

Comment: `Dim BoxNo, inspNo As Long` here you have declared `BoxNo` as a `Variant` and `inspNo` as `Long`.. You need to write it like this `Dim BoxNo As Long, inspNo As Long` if you want them both to be `Long`

Comment: before `tot` can you debug `m1` `m2` `m3`.. Also what is the actual error?